# Apache FOP : multiple page PDF from xml array list iteration

Tags: java, xml, apache, pdf, apache-fop

I have xml document that contains an array/list of complex elements. I would like to generate a PDF file such that each complex element is displayed on a new page. I have it working for a single page. My sample XML is like:

```
<root> <list><x><1>10</1><2>20</2></x> <x><1>11</1><2>22</2></x> <x><1>13</1><2>23</2></x></list> </root>
```

I have tried the following around

```
<xsl:for-each select="list/x">
<fo:page-sequence master-reference="my-page" initial-page-number="auto" format="1">
 <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
 <fo:block> 
         ... my fo:table etc here
      </fo:block>
      <fo:block id="SV_RefID_PageTotal" />
</fo:page-sequence>
</xsl:for-each>
```

I am getting validation errors. What am i doing wrong? Is there a better way to do such?
Thanks

Comment: Please list your errors.

Comment: What are the validation errors? Are they xsl-fo validation errors or are they errors because your sample XML is not well formed?

Answer (score 0):

Since they haven't been posted yet, I'm assuming your errors are because your XML is not well formed. Element names cannot start with a number. (See "XML Naming Rules" in [XML Elements](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_elements.asp))

I also did a quick XSL stylesheet that will generate valid XSL-FO. It's probably not what you want, but maybe you can use a piece or two from it?

**Modified Sample XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <list>
    <x>
      <c1>10</c1>
      <c2>20</c2>
    </x>
    <x>
      <c1>11</c1>
      <c2>22</c2>
    </x>
    <x>
      <c1>13</c1>
      <c2>23</c2>
    </x>
  </list>
</root>
```

**XSL Stylesheet**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="name() = 'root'">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>        
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="list">
    <fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
      <fo:layout-master-set>
        <fo:simple-page-master master-name="my-page">
          <fo:region-body/>
        </fo:simple-page-master>
      </fo:layout-master-set>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </fo:root>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="x">
    <fo:page-sequence master-reference="my-page" initial-page-number="auto" format="1">
      <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
        <fo:table>
          <fo:table-body>
            <fo:table-row>
              <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </fo:table-row>
          </fo:table-body>
        </fo:table>
      </fo:flow>
    </fo:page-sequence>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="c1|c2">
    <fo:table-cell>
      <fo:block>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </fo:block>
    </fo:table-cell>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XSL-FO**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
   <fo:layout-master-set>
      <fo:simple-page-master master-name="my-page">
         <fo:region-body/>
      </fo:simple-page-master>
   </fo:layout-master-set>
   <fo:page-sequence master-reference="my-page" initial-page-number="auto" format="1">
      <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
         <fo:table>
            <fo:table-body>
               <fo:table-row>
                  <fo:table-cell>
                     <fo:block>10</fo:block>
                  </fo:table-cell>
                  <fo:table-cell>
                     <fo:block>20</fo:block>
                  </fo:table-cell>
               </fo:table-row>
            </fo:table-body>
         </fo:table>
      </fo:flow>
   </fo:page-sequence>
   <fo:page-sequence master-reference="my-page" initial-page-number="auto" format="1">
      <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
         <fo:table>
            <fo:table-body>
               <fo:table-row>
                  <fo:table-cell>
                     <fo:block>11</fo:block>
                  </fo:table-cell>
                  <fo:table-cell>
                     <fo:block>22</fo:block>
                  </fo:table-cell>
               </fo:table-row>
            </fo:table-body>
         </fo:table>
      </fo:flow>
   </fo:page-sequence>
   <fo:page-sequence master-reference="my-page" initial-page-number="auto" format="1">
      <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
         <fo:table>
            <fo:table-body>
               <fo:table-row>
                  <fo:table-cell>
                     <fo:block>13</fo:block>
                  </fo:table-cell>
                  <fo:table-cell>
                     <fo:block>23</fo:block>
                  </fo:table-cell>
               </fo:table-row>
            </fo:table-body>
         </fo:table>
      </fo:flow>
   </fo:page-sequence>
</fo:root>
```

Comment: It was my mistake that i formed incorrect xml in my post, but that is not the case in my real scenario. My xml is well formed and is too large to post. The problem i see is that once my xml is generated, and i do xsl transformation to generate fo, it misses some elements and creates a blank table-body. And that is where i get the validation exception.

Comment: I greatly appreciate your response and am glad to get reply the same day. You guys are great.

Comment: Can someone redirect me to an example for iterating a list in apache fop